# How do I change the Git Bash Here terminal from mingw to the standard cmd OR powershell on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, git, powershell, cmd

I have started to absolutely HATE mingw as I seem to be unable to wrestle the right click option "Git bash here" away from mingw. I cant highlight anything in mingw and I cant copy paste. All I want is for the same functionality that cmd has on windows 10.

As such, how can I change my git bash to use system32/cmd.exe or powershell instead?

I have tried searching the registry, I have tried reinstalling.

Comment: If you don't mind the extra keystrokes, type 'cmd' on the bash shell that Git presents.

Comment: @gregg Sadly, this does not allow ctrl + c/v. However, it does work if I manually open the preferences and change the defaults to allow quick edit and ctrl key shortcuts. Thanks.

Comment: tat probably offtopic but people often thin of powershell.exe as being powershell itself which aint the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could edit the registry at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\git_shell\command` and 
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\git_shell\command` to point to the shell you prefer, or better yet add your own parallel entries.

The default property on first of these controls the popup menu when you right click on a blank area (background) in a explorer window, and the second when you right click on a folder.

If you are trying to do it from PowerShell, remember you can use provider-paths like `REGISTRY::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\git_shell\command` with Get-Item and Set-Item.   But if it's just a one-off, I'd use RegEdit so you won't have to deal with nested quotes.

Comment: This is what I did. But I happened to notice that the "quick edit mode" and "Enable ctrl key shortcuts" were not checked. Your answer, and the other answer I found here on stack overflow, works as long as you remember to activate those options I mentioned above. I wonder why they were off in the first place as when I opened cmd.exe by double clicking it was enabled. Thanks.

Comment: Did you set them with the "Defaults" menu item?  If you are using CMD.EXE, you should probably put a /K on the command line.

Comment: I just updated the values with "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe". I didnt add the /k. I just set the defaults to always use the ctrl shortcuts and to quickedit mode.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for answering an older question, but this is what helped me the most.

Simply reinstall it and it will ask you all the questions again (including if you want to use CMD or MinGW).

Going through the installer again works great, as it also allows me to choose (and possibly change, if wanted) any other options as well.